# How to implement JMS local queue using Spring 3.05 and JBoss 5.1 (JBossMQ)?

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

There is an application based on **Spring 3.0.5** framework running on **JBoss 5.1 server**.

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-jms-example/), but it uses the **ActiveMQ** broker instead of **JBossMQ** (default JBoss 5.1 broker).

I've already set a queue called **MyQueue** in JBoss config (destinations-service.xml):

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
  name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=MyQueue"
  xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
  <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
  <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
```

You can see the rest of my config below. What am I missing? How can I specify the JNDI name of the queue and the connection factory? And what about the server address ([ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://localhost:4457)?

My config in applicationContext.xml is as follow:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="messageDestination" class="javax.jms.Queue" />

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean id="springJmsProducer" class="myPackage.QueueProducer">
    <property name="destination" ref="messageDestination" />
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
</bean> 

<bean id="messageListener" class="myPackage.QueueConsumer" />
```

**My Producer**:

```
 public class QueueProducer {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private Queue queue;

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cf);
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {     
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void send(Object object) {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
              return session.createTextMessage("my text to send");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My Consumer**:

```
public class QueueConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            }catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is most likely `jndiTemplate`. Also, you're not quite wiring the `jmsTemplate` beans together correctly. Here's a piece by piece explanation of what you need in your Spring applicationContext.

You'll need to setup a jndiTemplate to inject the JBoss JNDI implementation:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">
                jnp://localhost:1099
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">
                org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then, configure the ConnectionFactory to point at the above JNDI config:

```
<!-- spring JMS definition -->
<bean name="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Configure the transaction manager with the above ConnectionFactory:

```
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Associate the destination with the jndiTemplate and jndiName:

```
<!-- jms destination already defined in jboss -->
<bean name="myQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="queue/MyQueue" />
</bean>
```

Finally, configure the jmsTemplate itself to point at the ConnectionFactory, and you're ready to use JmsTemplate in your code:

```
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

You'll also want a message listener container configuration to run your consumer. Replace "jmsexample.ExampleListener" with the name of the class that contains your MessageListener:

```
<!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
<bean id="messageListener" class="jmsexample.ExampleListener" />

<!-- and this is the message listener container -->
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="myQueue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```